# C# .NET Chart - Adding a legend scrollbar and checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, charts

I am using the Chart class in Visual Studio 2013 to visualize some of my data. However, my data quickly spawns many series and it's very important to have them all in one chart. I limited the legend area to 20% of the complete chart area, and so I pretty much cannot display more than 7-8 legend items when I stretch my chart to its maximum size. The control just puts ... after it runs out of space for legend items.

Instead of it just writing ..., is it somehow possible to add a scrollbar to the legend and be able to see all of the items? I am aware that I can implement my own legend in some way, but I would like to squeeze the most out of what the Chart class has to offer. I would also like to add checkboxes next to each legend item which would indicate whether the series should be hidden on the chart or not. Is this possible to do without my own legend implementation?

Additionally, I would also like to have a menu expand on right click on a legend item with a few options, but that's completely optional. Scrollbar and checkboxes are my main problem now.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt any of your wishes will come true out of the box. To expand the legend consider toggling the 20% limit you have set. But if you'll write a checkbox uo anyway it could replace the legend altogether and taske care of the menue as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General idea: You have to create two charts. One is main and second for legend only. You will have same series style if series order will be the same.

For showing pop up on right click on legend item:

Connect ContextMenu (ContextMenuStrip class in toolbox) to your legend's chart.

For showing hiding series from legend:

You have to implement `MouseClick` event handler and check what object is under mouse cursor using math (`GetChildAtPoint()` method doesn't work for legend items). Equation: is `series_index = control_relative_mouse_y / c_legendItemHeight` where `c_legendItemHeight` is value you provide to compute controls height (height of single legend item).
You have to configure your legend chart to contain `LegendStyle` to `Row`, `MaximumAutoSize` to `100`, `Docking` to `Left`, `IsTextAutoFit` to `false` and `IsEquallySpacedItems` to `true`.
You have define 3 columns in your legend (one for series style, second for checkbox and third for series name). Use series `CustomProperties` to keep visibility state. In check column use this custom property (Text = `"#CUSTOMPROPERTY(...)"`) to show check state. Chart does not support auto sizing. You can do it manually.  During series load set your chart height to calculated value. This value equals to `_stock.Shares.Count * c_legendItemHeight + 9`. Where: `_stock.Shares.Count` is number of items in legend, `c_legendItemHeight` constant height of item (integer value, numbers grater then 18 seems to work for me), `9` (seems to be constant). I know it is not nice but I cannot find any better solution. I've added 502 series in my example and it worked fine. Make sure that you don't have any margin in your chart because otherwise you will be not able to calculate series number correctly.

For "many series in legend" problem:

Put your legend chart into a panel with AutoScroll property turned on. Set panels and legends height using expression from above description.

Source code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int c_legendItemHeight = 20;
        private const string c_checkCustomPropertyName = "CHECK";
        private const string c_checkedString = "✔"; // see http://www.edlazorvfx.com/ysu/html/ascii.html for more
        private const string c_uncheckedString = "✘";
        private Stock _stock;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _stock = Stock.Load();

            // mainChart
            mainChart.Legends.Clear();
            foreach (Share share in _stock.Shares)
            {
                Series series = mainChart.Series.Add(share.Name);
                series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                foreach (ShareQuotation shareQuotation in share.Quotations)
                {
                    series.Points.AddXY(shareQuotation.Date.ToString(), shareQuotation.Close);
                }
            }

            // LegendChart
            Legend legend = legendChart.Legends[0];
            legendChart.Series.Clear();
            legend.IsTextAutoFit = false;
            legend.IsEquallySpacedItems = true;
            legend.MaximumAutoSize = 100;
            legend.Docking = Docking.Left;
            legend.LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Column;
            legend.Position.Auto = true;
            legend.Position.Width = 100;
            legend.Position.Height = 100;
            legend.CellColumns[1].Text = "#CUSTOMPROPERTY(" +c_checkCustomPropertyName+ ")";

            foreach (Share share in _stock.Shares)
            {
                Series series = legendChart.Series.Add(share.Name);
                series.SetCustomProperty(c_checkCustomPropertyName,c_checkedString);
            }
            legendChart.Height = _stock.Shares.Count * c_legendItemHeight + 9; // 9 - seems to be constant value
            legendPanel.Height = legendChart.Height;

        }



        private void legendChart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mousePosition = legendChart.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
            int seriesNo = mousePosition.Y / c_legendItemHeight;
            Series series = legendChart.Series[seriesNo]; // TODO - check if not out of range 

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                // check uncheck series
                if (series.GetCustomProperty(c_checkCustomPropertyName) == c_checkedString)
                {
                    // if checked
                    // uncheck
                    series.SetCustomProperty(c_checkCustomPropertyName, c_uncheckedString);
                    series.CustomProperties = series.CustomProperties; // workaround - trigger change - is this a bug?
                    // hide in mainChart
                    mainChart.Series[seriesNo].Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // if unchecked
                    legendChart.Series[seriesNo].SetCustomProperty(c_checkCustomPropertyName, c_checkedString);
                    series.CustomProperties = series.CustomProperties; // workaround - trigger change - is this a bug?
                    // show in mainChart
                    mainChart.Series[seriesNo].Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void contextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mousePosition = legendChart.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
            int seriesNo = mousePosition.Y / c_legendItemHeight;
            Series series = legendChart.Series[seriesNo]; // TODO - check if not out of range 

            contextMenu.Items.Clear();
            string state = series.GetCustomProperty(c_checkCustomPropertyName) == c_checkedString ? "visible" : "hidden";
            contextMenu.Items.Add("&Some strange action for " + state + " item named " + series.Name);
            contextMenu.Items.Add("&Another action ...");
        }
    }
```

[image: Main form code. 2 charts are added on the form one is main (<code>mainChart</code>) second is only for legend (<code>legendChart</code>). Legend chart is placed inside panel ('legendPanel`)]

Result should look like this:

Comment: In the end, I just hid the legend, but kept it active otherwise, and used its item to generate my custom legend. I think it was the most painless solution in my situation (unless somebody knows an out of the box solution).

Comment: Maybe you could create second Chart with legend only and attach scrollbar to it and in first chart disable legend. I think you should get the same style for series in both Chart controls.

Comment: We might be on something! How do you attach a scrollbar to a chart generally?

Comment: That actually sounds quite good, but the problem is I think there is no way to make the chart automatically expand vertically. In other words, the chart will follow the dimensions you specified. I also thought about adding a scrollable panel, but I don't know how to allow the chart to expand vertically.

Comment: Chart does not support auto sizing. You can do it manually. Change chart's `Height` property to calculated value. Be sure to turn off Legend's `IsTextAutoFit` property so you will have constant legend item size (if you don't use word warping in serie names).

Comment: That sounds nice. Even though I don't need it for the original scenario, now I need it for something else. Now my question is - is there a way to exactly calculate the resolution at which everything is fully displayed?

Comment: Did you mean whole chart? Chart is rendered on whole space available to control. You can check particular chart part sizes by accessing Position property of particular object. I will move some parts of my comments to answer if were helpful.

Comment: Yes, your comments were certainly very useful! :) I would still like to see someone do what I originally wanted (even though it's probably impossible with this version of chart), but thanks for the tips about resizing to fit the legend.

Comment: Update: Legends Position property is relative (in percents) so you cannot base on that. Sorry for misleading comment.

Comment: You are very kind to me. Thank you. My only concern is height calculation - I should be able to do it nicer - but couldn't find better solution. Do not hesitate to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: While this might not be EXACTLY what I was looking for, it is very close and it gives me a lot of hints, and I am sure many people will find it very useful. As for the height calculation, I was thinking about it for a while myself, but it shouldn't be a problem. Thank you again.